# How to prevent a user from adding or removing printers?

Tags: printing

How to prevent a user from adding or removing printers?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using a PolKit policy. There are a few printer-related Polkit actions:

```
$ pkaction | grep -i print
org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.printer-enable
org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.printer-local-edit
org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.printer-remote-edit
org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.printer-set-default
org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.printeraddremove
```

The last one seems to be the most relevant. Create a `.pkla` file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` named, say, `disable-printer-change.pkla`, containing:

```
[Printer addition, removal]
Identity=unix-user:geraldo
Action=org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.printeraddremove
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Replace `geraldo` with the appropriate username. Wildcards are supported, and you can also use `groups` using `unix-group:<group-name>`.