# Disable Manual option to change date and time in ubuntu

Tags: gnome

I have a non root user in my ubuntu desktops the user can change the time manually from Gnome. I have installed a NTP Server in my environment. Now, I don't want this user to be able to set the time manually. What I exactly want is to disable the "manual" option from date and time settings on All Gnome date and time settings windows.

Comment: The polkit policy `org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-time` would be the one. You could adapt http://askubuntu.com/a/582233/158442 to use this policy.

Comment: Hi Friend ,

Thanks for your response on this in my desktop I am getting below mentioned polkit policies for time 


root@cctnsserver:/etc/polkit-1/localauthority# pkaction |grep -i time           org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.acquire-high-priority
org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.acquire-real-time
org.gnome.settingsdaemon.datetimemechanism.configure

Can you please suggest me which one I should use