# How to block access to changing clock and date for ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, time, date

My name is Daniel, 
I am work in IT support. I have a problem on my finger print installed on Ubuntu. Date and time system in ubuntu can be edited by the user, so the user late to the office and change the date and time system on ubuntu. 
There are any software used to block access to changing clock and date for ubuntu?
There are any solution?

Thank You.

Comment: Why not rather use a server based recording system with limited access? Then the times for everyone would be the same and not dependent on the sync of each client??

Answer (score 4):

For the GUI, you need to set Polkit rules. Adapting [one of my other answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/582233/158442), check which Polkit actions apply:

```
$ pkaction | grep time
com.canonical.controlcenter.datetime.configure
org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.acquire-high-priority
org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.acquire-real-time
org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-local-rtc
org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-ntp
org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-time
org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-timezone
```

The `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1` actions are not relevant here, you can ignore those and deny permission for the others. Create a `.pkla` file in /`etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` named, say, `disable-time-change.pkla`, containing:

```
[Disable time change]
Identity=*
Action=com.canonical.controlcenter.datetime.configure;org.freedesktop.timedate1.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

You can be more specific about which users shouldn't be able to this by replacing the `*` in `Identity=*` with the appropriate usernames or groups (`unix-user:foo;unix-group:bar`, etc.).

For the command line, don't give them unrestricted `sudo` access.

Answer (score -1):

The Unity system settings for date/time appears to have root privilege, or perhaps `unity-control-center datetime` notifies `/lib/systemd/systemd-timedated`.  As an extreme solution you could rename unity-control-center and that would stop the user from making any settings including date, power, screen, etc.