# How do I allow non-admin users to control printers?

Tags: permissions, printing, users, policykit

An Ubuntu (21.10) PC is shared among a number of users, most of whom are not administrators. They are not allowed to install/remove/update software or directly alter system files, nevertheless all of them should be able to do anything with printers (manage print queues, remove printers, add new printers etc) i.e. enjoy full admin rights in the printing section of the settings window. How can this possibly be achieved?

Comment: Does it help to add them to the `lpadmin` group?

Comment: Looks the opposite of https://askubuntu.com/a/582233/158442

Comment: @Jos I'll try and provide feedback, thank you for a clue.

Answer (score 5):

See

```
/etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

it will have 2 lines like this

```
# Administrator user group...
SystemGroup sys root
```

add `lpadmin` behind `root` (restart cups with `sudo systemctl restart cups`) and then add your users to the group `lpadmin`. From the browser URL {hostname}:631 can then be used to configure printers by users in the group `lpadmin`.

Comment: regarding Rinzwind's answer if you don't find `#Administrator user group...` in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`, check `/etc/cups/cups-file.conf` where you will find roughly the same thing as # Administrator user group, used to match @SYSTEM in cupsd.conf policy rules... # This cannot contain the Group value for security reasons... SystemGroup root